# How always enable Chrome Devtools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I tried the command:

`chrome.exe --always-enable-dev-tools`

but it doesn't exist: http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc&l=50

Do you have another solution?

Comment: If it doesn't exist, why did you try it? What are you trying to achieve specifically? Dev Tools can be accessed any time by pressing Ctrl+Shift+I on a PC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I edited the source of "browser_navigator.cc". Now I have the devtools each new tab or window.

How: edit the source file **browser_navigator.cc**

**include**

```
#include "chrome/browser/debugger/devtools_toggle_action.h"
#include "chrome/browser/debugger/devtools_window.h"
#include "content/public/browser/devtools_manager.h"
```

**and after**

```
LoadURLInContents(params->target_contents->tab_contents(),url, params, extra_headers);
```

**I add**

```
 DevToolsWindow::ToggleDevToolsWindow(params->target_contents->tab_contents()->GetRenderViewHost(),DEVTOOLS_TOGGLE_ACTION_NONE);
```

and make :)

Answer (score 0):

Refer the link below for chrome Devtools:

http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html

http://google-chrome-browser.com/tags/devtools

Comment: When it runs I want the devtools is open.
The documentation doesn't inform on how to